# Ubuntu live disk stop halt in the boot process

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have just bought a new ASUS laptop for my son. It have pre-installed Windows 8.1. I made my usb-live stick as I use to and tried install ubuntu.
It use to be simple.

I switch off fast-boot in bios and also the fast-boot in windows.
I selected to boot the usb in the bios.
The laptop boot up grub and I select Install.
After this the ubuntu shows the slash screen as usual.
But the boot process halts.
The boot console prints the following message.

```
staring version 219 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/casper.service:10] Failed to parse input specifier, ignoring: force-tty
```

And after this nothing happens (The machine is frozen).

Note.
I have tried with Xubuntu 14.04, Xubuntu 15.04, Kubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.04
Same result on all four distributions.

The laptop is 
ASUS F553MA Celeron 4GB 500GB HDD 15.6"

It used to be very easy to install ubuntu.
But for the last 2-3 years it is just getting more and more difficult.

I don't need the Windows OS. 
So how can I install ubuntu if I can boot from a live usb.

Comment: How did you create the Live USB? [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) gives the best results...

Answer (score -1):

Same here. Asus n56vm trying Kubuntu with DVD as source.

It only works with Ubuntu, I mean with unity, at least in my PC.

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, welcome to askubuntu! Take a moment to [take the tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) and read [the help](http://askubuntu.com/help) to learn what constitutes a good answer. I'm afraid yours does not qualify as it is a) not contributing to a solution and b) does not even seem to be about the same problem. You seem to be able to run Ubuntu and use the Unity shell. OPs computer doesn't even boot properly.